# Looking for "pad" for my keyboard + mouse in a multi-monitor setup

Tags: keyboard, multiple-monitors, work-environment

I've got 2 large monitors. My keyboard and mouse are in the middle of my desk which is appropriate for work on both monitors but when I want to focus on one of them only (say that I'm writing in MS Word on the right monitor), I'd like to move my keyboard and mouse to the right. I can do that manually but because of all the wires and other things, it is quite inconvenient when done frequently.

I'm looking for something that I would put under both my keyboard and my mouse and that would slide to one side or the other easily. Is there anything like that available on the market?

Answer (score 0):

> I can do that manually but because of all the wires and other things, it is quite inconvenient when done frequently.

Get a USB hub and put it behind your keyboard, then tie up the cables between the keyboard/mouse until you have the shortest length needed.

This assumes you have a USB keyboard and mouse.